# Jenkins - trigger builds automatically after server restart

Tags: deployment, jenkins, restart

Is it possible to trigger Jenkins to run jobs after server is restarted (that is, when Jenkins is started, for example)?

I thought this would be pretty simple but haven't found answer with brief googling.

Backround is that our Jenkins automatically deploys two Play applications after their tests pass at the same server for test use. (For both applications, we have a test build that triggers deployment build). Now it would be nice that applications would be up and running after server reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an app... err plugin, for that :)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Startup+Trigger